Concatenate environment variables in application.yaml
I'm trying to append a system environment to a database connection string.
I have a Kubernetes cluster running with minikube, where a pod is running with a MySQL image and has a service with ClusterIP, and another pod running my back-end Java application using a service with LoadBalancer.
I want to refer to the environment variable that is being made for the service by kubernetes, and I'm not sure if I'm doing it properly. When I refer to the environment variable SERVICENAME_SERVICE_HOST in my Spring application, I get the ip address. However, it seems to fail to set the JDBC URL in my application.yaml. I suspect that I am not concatenating the environment variable properly as it worked fine when I used localhost instead of environment variable when both pods used a LoadBalancer and shared the same service in Kubernetes.
My application.yaml file:
spring:
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
    show-sql: true
  datasource:
    url: "jdbc:mysql://${SQL_SERVICE_SERVICE_HOST}:3306/peopledb?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true"
    username: root
    password: "${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}"
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

deployment/service for Kubernetes:
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: backend-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: backend
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 8080
    targetPort: 8080
    name: backend
  type: LoadBalancer
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: sql-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: mysql
  ports:
  - port: 3306
    targetPort: 3306
    name: mysql
  type: ClusterIP
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: backend-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: backend
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: backend
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: backend
        image: <imagelink redacted>
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mysql-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mysql
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mysql
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: mysql
        image: mysql:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3306
        env:
        - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
          value: "mysecret"

EDIT: The marked answer is a smart and better way to use environment variables from kubernetes that can be applied in spring. However i noticed why my attempt didnt work. It seems like i just forgot to define the environment variable in the deployment for my backend(MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD)... i only did it for the deployment of sql container. So it failed because it didnt have a valid password, not because it couldnt fetch the ip address of the service. After adding the environment variable to the backend container/deployment aswell it works as it should

This is a pretty unfortunate example to pick. You can just use the proper dns name for the service instead of the environment variable. It's just as much typing but can be generated from inside your Helm chart. Additionally, the documentation has this caveat: "you must create the Service before the client Pods come into existence". You have no control over this if you deploy everything at once.

@Botje I agree it would be easier to just type in the dns name. Im trying to learn a little about networking in kubernetes, and i wanted to see how i could make 2 pods communicate with one another where one pod uses a service that can be reached from outside the cluster, and the other can only be reached internally in the cluster. This is all just to get the grasp on how things work

I'd address this entirely at the Kubernetes level.  You can set Spring properties directly from environment variables, and you can do basic string concatenation in Kubernetes environment variables.  In your Pod spec (that is, in the Deployment) you can set
env:
  - name: SQL_SERVICE_SERVICE_HOST
    value: sql-service
  - name: SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL
    value: jdbc:mysql://$(SQL_SERVICE_SERVICE_HOST):3306/peopledb?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
  - name: SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD
    value: mysecret
    # valueFrom: { secretKeyRef: { ... } }

This approach avoids needing to recompile the jar file if you change a Kubernetes-oriented setting (you're not changing a src/main/resources/application-*.yml file).  You don't really need the intermediate SQL_SERVICE_SERVICE_HOST variable here but it can be useful to have the hostname and database name as separate variables in some cases.

Thank you so much for the answer! Im relatively new at this, so took a while to wrap my head around it and implement the solution. It works now with backend and sql being in their separate pods/services and sql using clusterip while backend uses loadbalancer.
